# setResult not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

In my first activity, I call second activity this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_TAG);
```

And then in the second activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    setResult(AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Back in the first activity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case SOME_TAG:
            if (resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                doStuff();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

For some reason the result code is never equal to RESULT_OK, it's just coming back 0 every time.

Comment: Can you verify that your `onBackPressed()` method is being called?

Comment: It is being called, yes

Comment: And you have no other calls to `setResult` (in, for instance, `onPause()` or `onStop()`) that might override this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you are not actually sending the data back. You have to call `finish()` to return to the activity and essentially close it. Here is the documentation for this method: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish(). Just call this after `setResult(AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)` in the `onBackPressed()` method. Hope it helps!

Comment: When OP calls `super.onBackPressed()`, that generally leads to a call to `finish()`.

Comment: True, id you try adding `finish()` to the method?

Comment: Adding finish() worked. I had assumed it was built into the super method of onBackPressed(), but good to know! Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked! Could you please accept this answer, so other users know you found your solution?